# Creating an Alpine.js sortable directive

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I'm trying to create an Alpine sortable directive which uses [SortableJS](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable) to sort an array. So far I managed to create the directive and sort the (HTML) elements.

```js
Alpine.directive('sortable', (el, { expression }, { evaluate }) => {
    let options = evaluate(expression)
    Sortable.create(el, {
        ...options,
        animation: 150,
        onEnd() {
            // Reorder stuff?
            // Example:
            const sorted = [];
            el.childNodes.forEach(node => {
                if (node.dataset && node.dataset.id) {
                    sorted.push(node.dataset.id);
                }
            });
            console.log(sorted);
        }
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, this is quite useless because the underlying data will not be reordered. I think the following things need to be addressed:

- Getting the :key attribute when looping over the childNodes
- Access the parent (companies) array and recreate this array based on the order of the :key
- Repopulate the companies data with the newly sorted array

I've created a codepen with some basic functionality: [codepen.io/V1nznt/pen/WNJpewo](https://codepen.io/V1nznt/pen/WNJpewo)

Any Alpine experts who can help me out? I'm guessing this would also be a nice usecase to add to the [Alpine components](https://alpinejs.dev/components#integrations) page.